# Newton Pepys Problem

Tags: probability

I could not understand the intuition behind using combination in calculating probability so could anyone show me the non combination way of solving and understanding problem. Probability of six in dice is $\frac{1}{6}$ and other number beside six is $\frac{5}{6}$ so if I want exactly one six then we will say ${ C }_{ 12 }^{ 1 }\frac{1}{6}{\left( \frac{5}{6}\right)}^{11}$. However I could not get the intuition behind this. I understood that it is like $P(A$ or $B$ or $C...)$ and that's the reason we use combination as six could turn up anywhere, even then mind is supposedly not accepting that.

Comment: It is not an intuition issue: You compute the ratio between the number of events that are approved to the total potential events. Combination is just a mean for computing number of events

Comment: You are only not understanding the $^{12}C_1$ part ?

Comment: You don't say how many dice you are rolling. The probability you gave is the probability of rolling exactly one 6 when you roll 12 dice, but that is not any of the probabilities in the Newton-Pepys problem.

Comment: Yeah I could not understand 12C1 part? Can someone show non binomial way of calculating it?

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote a 6 by **S** and a non-six by **N** and assume 2**S** & 4 **N**

**One** way the desired event could occur is **S S N N N N**, with Pr = $(\frac{1}{6})^2 \cdot (\frac{5}{6})^4$

But the two **S**'s could occur anywhere in the sequence, i.e. they could be *placed* in $^6C_2$ ways, so we multiply by $^6C_2$

Or, using the formula for permutations with repetitions, we could say that the sequence has $\dfrac {6!}{2!4!}$ permutations, which is identical to the formula $^6C_2$ expanded

Since $^6C_2$ or ${6\choose 2}$ is a more compact way of expressing, we use it.